# HTML5 Draggable Element Being Clipped

Tags: html, draggable, html5-draggable

I've added `draggable="true"` to an element, and only the visible part of the element is being dragged. The rest of the element is clipped. How can I get the entire element to show?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this myself, because I couldn't find any answers on this when I was searching.

My problem was that `overflow: hidden;` was being set on one of the parent elements which was causing the clipping. Removing that, and setting styling another way was able to fix the issue.